# Seperate html for initial download of chrome extenion

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a simple chrome extension that when initially downloaded will request a phone number through a text box in the popup.html. However, after the initial download is completed and a phone number is given, I want to show a seperate html which shows something else. I am not totally sure how to achieve this. I have a default popup in my manifest.json, but how do I change that after installation. I am aware chrome extensions have chrome.runtime.onInstalled, but I am not sure if that is what I need. I have attached my manifest.json, popup.html, and listener for my popup.html.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
 
  "name": "Top Shot Notifications",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Lateral blog post demo extension",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://www.google.com/*",
    "storage"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"

}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">           
        <h3>Hello,</h3>
        <p>Please enter your phone number: </p>         
        <input id="phone_number" />                   
        <button id="start" type="button">START</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </div> 
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function startScripts() {
    var phone_number = document.getElementById('phone_number').value;
    chrome.storage.local.set({ phone_number: phone_number});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
              file: 'content.js'
            });
}
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', startScripts);
```